# Zebra Scanner simultaneously scanning

Tags: zebra-scanners

I am using Zebra Enterprise Browser and Zebra Android Scanner and the normal scanning process
working fine with EB.Barcode.enable({allDecoders:true})in javascript.
Now my Question is how is it possible to change in the code the mode from
single scan to simultaneously (multiscan)?

```
function fnScanEnable() { 
     EB.Barcode.enable({allDecoders:true},fnBarcodeScanned); 
      document.getElementById('scanData').value 
   = "enabled: press HW trigger to capture.";   
}
function fnBarcodeScanned(jsonObject) {
  console.log("Barcode Scanned:{" + JSON.stringify(jsonObject) + "}");
  document.getElementById('scanData').value = "barcode: " + jsonObject.data;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello i found the solution see below:
EB.Barcode.scanMode =  EB.Barcode.SCANMODE_MULTI_BARCODE;
EB.Barcode.barcodeCount =  3;
barcodeCount means Sets the number of barcodes (integer from 2–8 to scan at one time